# Promises - Get parameter from storage

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ionic2

Im new with Promises, I found out that I have to use Promises to get the saved information from local storage. I guess the post request get called before I set
`params.set('az_key', data)`. How can I solve that? Tried the return statement within the Promise, but this causes errors.

```
public call(params : URLSearchParams) {

  this.storage.getAZKey().then(data=>{
    console.log(data);
    params.set('az_key', data);  
    console.log("AZ-Key: " + params.get("az_key"));
  })

  console.log("Token for XXrequest: " + params.get("az_key")); // gives me null 

      return this.http
     .post("http://localhost:8080/Info", params)
     .map(res => res.text())

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need promises to get something from the localstorage.

To set something:

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");
```

To get something:

```
localStorage.getItem("username");
```

Note: you can only set and get strings.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

But for your async problem; you're right that your post request "might" get called before you set your param since these are async functions.

One way could be to chain these async functions like:

```
public call(params : URLSearchParams) {
    return this.storage.getAZKey().then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        params.set('az_key', data);  
        console.log("AZ-Key: " + params.get("az_key"));
      }).then(data=>{
          console.log("Token for XXrequest: " + params.get("az_key")); // gives me null 

          return this.http
         .post("http://localhost:8080/Info", params)
         .map(res => res.text())

      })
}
```

And while you are consuming this method:

```
this.servletService.call(params).then((obs)=>{
   obs.subscribe(
   (data)=>{
     console.log(data);
   },
   (err)=>{console.log(err);})
});
```

Comment: But I'm using the @ionic/storage

Comment: @SaskiaB I updated my answer for your async issue. But if you are getting errors inside the callback, this might not work too. What kind of errors were you getting?

Comment: I have a subscriber on the call method: `this.servletService.call(params).subscribe(...)` , when I do it like you did above it says `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'`

Comment: @SaskiaB oh I'm sorry I forgot the return of promise. I updated my answer with a return statement for the promise.

Comment: but still can't use subscribe on it.

Comment: @SaskiaB yes because you need to first `.then` the promise then subscribe to the observable that comes within it.

Comment: @SaskiaB Which one? How?

Comment: .post("http://localhost:8080/Info", params) ..  the webservice does not react, I have a breakpoint set there and loggin the parameter normally it should spring into. But it seems like the URI get not called .

Comment: @SaskiaB Check the network tab for what response you are getting

Comment: @SaskiaB ah, glad you figured it out.